# Вывести уникальные символы и посчитать их количество с помощью Dictionary C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string buffer = "Hello world";
char[] ch = buffer.ToCharArray();
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(ch[i]))
    {
        dict.Add(ch[i], 1);

    }
    else
    {
        dict.TryGetValue(ch[i], out count );
        dict[ch[i]]++;
       
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Количество символов {0} = {1}", ch[i], );
}
```

Не понимаю, какой метод использовать, чтобы изъять значение по ключу и чтобы оно считало.

Comment: Как перебрать элементы словаря: https://stackoverflow.com/a/141105/8324991

Answer (score 1):

Результаты подсчёта нужно выводить после окончания подсчёта, отдельным циклом по словарю

```
foreach(var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Количество символов {0} = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```