# Извлечь значение из словаря и подсчитать количество уникальных символов

Tags: c#

Найти количество уникальных элементов в строке и вывести их количество с помощью словаря.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

string buffer = "Hello world";
char[] ch = buffer.ToCharArray();
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(ch[i]))
    {
        dict.Add(ch[i], 1);

    }
    else
    {
        dict.TryGetValue(ch[i], out count );
       
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Количество символов {0} = {1}", ch[i], );
}
```

Я новичок в `С#`, но хочется разобраться в данной задаче. Сижу уже не первый день, но не могу найти и использовать метод после `else`. Чтобы извлекать пару код-значение и считать количество уникальных символов.

Comment: Отличия в чем от предыдущего вопроса? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1463137/220553

Comment: Извините, просто в своем профиле не увидела, что опубликовался предыдущий